# Opentok black screen issue

Tags: ios, swift, webrtc, opentok, tokbox

I am using `Opentok` code for my swift program.
I have two questions.

1) I use same session in my two UIViewcontrollers.
Once I open my connection with the session, should I close it before opening /connecting it in the second page?

2) sometime I am getting black screen insead of subscribers video. I use the static session  created in the trial version.

Please advice.

Comment: have you testing on real devices or simulater? because simulater have no camera.

Comment: yes, in real devices  iPhone 6S and iPhone 5S

Comment: two reasons for black screen.... 1. because of internet  2. if your Session is expired

Comment: 1. I have a reliable net connection
2. Session is till there.
But one question I have selected the media mode option as Routed, not as Relayed. I need this app for 1-1 chat. Will this be an issue?
also this happens not every time....

Comment: Relayed type is not supported group video calling... Routed is for group and 1 -1 chat both. I am using Routed and its working fine

Comment: you can try Relayed for 1-1 calling.

Comment: Ok, can you please tell whether I have to close the connection while I enter to a new window, or without closing again call doconnect()

Answer (score 0):

```
var error: OTError? = nil
session.disconnect(error)
if error != nil {
print("disconnect failed with error: (\(error))")
}
session(session, streamDestroyed: stream)
```

Comment: call this in viewWillDisappear  ?

Comment: Ok, I shall try this.

Comment: This code throws two errors.
1) Cannot invoke 'disconnect' with an argument list of type '(OTError?)'
2) Cannot call value of non-function type 'OTSession'
---
here is my class https://github.com/opentok/opentok-ios-sdk-samples-swift/blob/master/Basic-Video-Chat/Basic-Video-Chat/ViewController.swift